# Video as Background image ionic app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I was wondering if there was a way to do a cross-platform background video without using GIF.

Much like the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2), however, with MP4 and not GIF as I'd like to use a longer video.

I'd like to use this on a login screen, like the current Uber app.

Comment: [Apparently](https://www.designernews.co/stories/22596-what-are-some-examples-of-good-html5-mobile-apps), Uber is a cordova application running a webview. However, are they using native hooks on the opening view to run the video?

Answer (score 2):

This should work: or at least put you on the right path: will it work once compiled? I do not know. Also make sure your video is high enough resolution to fill the space. **EDIT:** had to remove ion-content to get it to scale right:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
           <video autoplay loop poster="" id="bgvid">

    <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">

    <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#bgvid {

position: fixed;

top: 50%;

left: 50%;

min-width: 100%;

min-height: 100%;

width: auto;

height: auto;

z-index: -100;

-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

background: url(http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm) no-repeat;

background-size: cover;

}
```

Playground: http://play.ionic.io/app/5157ac74b69b

Comment: Does not work in the iphone sim, assume same on device [screenshot](https://imgur.com/PEDz4nn), thanks for trying!!!

Comment: that is cause ios automatically disables videos playing on mobile to save data on iphones. There is no way to get a background video to play as far as I know. Try doing what I did with a gif, maybe that is the only way to do it for IOS

Comment: Does anyone know if this at least works on Android when compiled? If not, I will test and report back.

Comment: There should be a way. Facebook's app in iphone does the autoplay.

Comment: @BraianMellor yeah but facebook uses native code not a hybrid app. pretty much an angular/ionic app is just like a web browser.

Comment: There should be a way, facebooks is not the only app. https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:278001 @JessPatton I've tested your example and works perfect, but not in iphone

Comment: does this have anyting do with the ios browser??? see this: https://html5backgroundvideos.com/how-to-create-a-html5-background-video-using-html-css-and-javascript/
they say: iOS doesn’t play nice with video backgrounds – it will add it’s own play button, which when clicked will open up the media player.
ios does not like it which is sad :(

Comment: @JessPatton that page in iphone doesn't work. Also I went inside iphone's safari and autoplay isn't working. I'll try touching screen if i can set play the videos as background with vimeo, but tomorrow, today it's too late

Comment: @JessPatton it's definitely possible to have background videos in hybrid apps, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005599/use-video-as-a-background-in-ionic-cordova-for-ios

Comment: @pgorsira you are correct, I never said it was not possible. All I said was that iphones and ipads disable background video autoplay by defualt.