# Use video as a background in ionic/cordova for ios

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm needing to play like 6 videos as background in differents divs at the same time, but in IOS and ANDROID platforms. I'm developing an ionic app.

I've found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060664/1678851) that works perfectly with web, but when I builded it up, it worked as I supposed: every video that I used as background just play as full screen.

Here goes some code:

```css
.bg-vid {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: 100%;;
 z-index: -100;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
   <div>
    <video autoplay muted loop class="bg-vid">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
   </div>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So for this issue as used 2 things.

First one, on config.xml added the next line

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
```

And after add the webkit-playsinline directive inside the video tag like this:

```
<video controls preload="auto" webkit-playsinline><source src="videos/video_file.mp4"></video>
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: where to put the video.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: the path i meant, if i put relative path in the src(local file-present in the project). so how to put it

Comment: just put the path to the video, what's the problem? can't you find the video? can you send me an example?

Comment: It doesn't loop for me for some reason... All else works well.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that the above answer is correct, except for the fact that with recent iOS updates to the video tag, the video must also have the **muted** property set to true in order to allow autoplay without user gesture.

```
<video controls preload="auto" autoplay playsinline muted loop><source src="videos/video_file.mp4"></video>
```

I spent all of last night trying to figure this one out, and I hope that this helps someone else out there.